# LWC table with lightning-record-edit-form functionality

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

I need to create a table that can be edited. Doesn't necessarily have to be a "table" (def not a datatable). Can someone suggest a direction for me? I want to be able to have the fields look like they do in a lightning-record-edit-form / lightning-input-field so I get the picklist, lookup etc functionality.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) component to show records, and they can be editable.

Also, you can use the [lightning-record-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation) component to create new records.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create a table with editable fields that have similar functionality to the [lightning-record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) or [lightning-input-field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field) components in Lightning.

You can achieve this by using custom Lightning components or building the table with HTML and JavaScript. You may want to consider using the LWC and the lightning-input or lightning-combobox components to create the table fields.

These components provide built-in functionality for picklists, lookups, and other types of input fields.